# Implication in the $(ε,δ)$-definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits, logic, definition, epsilon-delta

I'm still confused by the use of  $\Rightarrow$  in (ε,δ)-definition of limit.  
Take for example the definition of $\underset{x\rightarrow x_{0}}{\lim}f\left(x\right)=l$ :

> $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\;\exists\delta>0\quad\mathrm{such\:that\quad}\forall x\in\mathrm{dom}\,f,\;0<\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta\;\Rightarrow\;\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$$

My questions are:

Why is $\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$ not a sufficient condition for $0<\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta\;$?

Or, stated in another way, shouldn't $\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon\;\Rightarrow\;0<\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta\;$ also be true ? 
If $f\left(x\right)$ becomes arbitrarily close to $l$, doesn't $x$  becomes arbitrarily close to $x_0$?

Comment: Suppose for instance that $f $ is constant (with value $l $).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already given example of constant function should (in my opinion) be enough to shoot the whole idea down in a blazing glory, but parabola might be more convincing visually:

[image]

As we can see, $\lim_{x\to -2} x^2 = \lim_{x\to 2} x^2 = 4$, and when we are getting close to the limit $4$ on the $y$-axis, it could be that we are either close to $2$ or $-2$, but most definitely we can't get close to both at the same time.

Comment: So basically my definition does not work, except for injective functions. 
Am I  right?

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, actually, no. Restrict $x\mapsto x^2$ to positive reals and take the same limit. Then $-1 < x^2 -4 < 1 \iff \sqrt 3 - 2 < x-2 < \sqrt 5 - 2$, so such $\delta$ would exist for $\varepsilon = 1$. Notice that interval that is the preimage is not symmetric around $2$.

Comment: If i restrict $x^2$ to positive reals, doesn't it become injective in the positive reals?

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, of course it does, otherwise it wouldn't be counterexample to your claim. And now that I think about it, the mere condition in the definition that $0<|x-x_0|$ already breaks the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry . I phrased my first question wrongly

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, if it's not clear enough, $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \implies 0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ can be rephrased as $f^{-1}(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon) = (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus \{x_0\}$ which definitely isn't true.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the definition in that way would mean that a *constant function* cannot have a limit, for example.

Or as a less trivial example, consider for example $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac1x$. Intuitively this ought to be $1$, but with your addition to the definition the limit would not exist. Namely, if I choose $\varepsilon=2$ then you can't find any $\delta$ such that $|\frac1x-1|<2$ is only true when $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks to all of you for the answers. I still don't understand why in the proof of limits we assume that $\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$ in order to derive that $0<\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta$. Shouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: @DavideLaVardera: If you want to prove that $l$ is a limit from the definition, you should assume that somebody gives you an unknown $\varepsilon$ and then you need to come up with a $\delta$ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-l|$. You may be confused by didactic presentation that are about _exploring_ how one might find a $\delta$ that will work -- but this exploration is _not part of the proof_, just an illustration of the thought process that could lead you to _discover_ details that will allow the proof to work.

Comment: Why can't we derive ε given a certain δ?

Comment: @DavideLaVardera: The definition says that for each $\varepsilon$ there must be a qualifying $\delta$. If you start with an arbitrary $\delta$ and work your way to an $\varepsilon$ that works with that, you won't have any guarantee that all possible $\varepsilon$s get a $\delta$.

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, it's because the definition says $\forall\varepsilon\,\exists\delta$ and not $\forall\delta\,\exists\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Ennar: I know that the definition says ∀ε∃δ  and not ∀δ∃ε. I was wondering about the reason behind it

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, its because the question is: "How close do I need to be to $x_0$ for $f$ to be this close to $l$?" and not "If I get this close to $x_0$, how close will $f$ be to $l$?". Contemplate on the difference. I'll give you an example on the second question. Let $f\equiv 0$ and let $l = 1000$. Then for any $\delta>0$ there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x) - 1000| < \varepsilon$. Namely, it is $\varepsilon = 1001$. What would that tell you of the limit?

Comment: @Ennar: If I can be completely honest with you, I don't now what to say about that limit :D
I rephrase: Why the question is "How close do I need to be to $x_0$ for $f$ to be this close to $l$?" and NOT "If I get this close to $x_0$, how close will $f$ be to $l$?"?

Comment: @Davide La Vardera, well, precisely, if you consider the second thing, it tells you nothing of the limit compared to the first one. Look, you need to figure this out on your own, you can variate the definition in many ways. Check yourself why each variation fails to tell you what $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ is for $f(x)$ constant, $x^2+1$, $\operatorname{sgn} x$ and any other simple function you can think of.

Comment: @Ennar: I just realized that we are searching for $\delta$ because $0<\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta\;\implies\;\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$ and not the opposite. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You can think about it in this way:

> first set $\epsilon$ and then you have to find $\delta$ such that the inequality:
>
> $$\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$$
>
> is satisfied.

If you can do it for every $\epsilon>0$ then the limit exists.